# how to upgrade phpunit`s PHP_CodeCoverage

Tags: phpunit

I have the problem of upgrading my phpunit with pyrus, and it always output something like:

```
Pyrus\Installer\Exception: Dependency validation failed for some packages to install, installation aborted  
Pyrus\Dependency\Exception: pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit requires    package "channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage" (version >= 1.2.1), installed version is 1.2.0  
Pyrus\Dependency\Exception: pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit can optionally use package "channel://pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Invoker" (version >= 1.1.0)
```

I have use the -f flag to force upgrade my phpunit from 3.7.0 to 3.7.1, but other packages still not upgrade.

I have tried to use the command **php pyrus.phar upgrade phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage** to upgrade PHP_CodeCoverage, but I got the something like:

```
Skipping installed package pear.phpunit.de/PHP_CodeCoverage
```

How can I upgrade ohter package separatly?

Answer (score 0):

Try `--alldeps` flag, should help: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.commandline.installing.php